# cannot find symbol- variable y right under my report heading where it says "y=InputNumber"

Tags: java, computer-science

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project4
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("data4.txt"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("output1.txt"));
        out.printf(" Tanner Triggs  Project 4\n");
        out.printf(" Due 10/18/13 Professor Barker");
        y=InputNumber(); 
        int divisor = 2;
        ctr = 0;
        out.printf("\n For the number %4d the prime factors are", InputNumber);
        ctr++;

        do
        {
            int remainder = InputNumber% divisor;
            if (remainder = 0)
            {
                out.print(",  " +divisor);
                InputNumber = InputNumber/divisor;
            }
            else
            {
                divisor++;
            }
        }while (divisor!=y);
        InputNumber = input.nextInt();

        out.printf("\n\n%d set of numbers factored" , ctr);
        input.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `y` supposed to be?

Comment: YOu need to define variable `type` for `y`, `ctr ` and `InputNumber`. And where is your `InputNumber()` method

Answer (score 0):

You didn't ever declare a variable named `y`. Java is strongly typed, which means that you have to tell it what type each variable has (in contrast to languages like Ruby or Javascript, where you can put any kind of value in any variable). Add the line `int y;` above your assignment, or make the assignment `int y = InputNumber();`.

Additionally, you use two `InputNumber`s, one method (with parentheses) and one variable (without), but you're never declaring either of those, either. It's generally a bad idea to name both a variable and a method the same thing; it gets confusing in a hurry. Finally, it's customary in Java to lowercase the first letter of method and variable names to distinguish them from class names.